# open a port for sending emails

Tags: php, windows

Im having trouble being able to send an email. I've tried using Yahoo and Gmail but it seems to be on my end where there isn't a port to send emails from. Do I have to ask my ISP to open up a port on my connection or do I have to open up a port on my machine or the server and if so could some one give me the step/directions to open up a port on my machine or on the server. I have a server which I connect to the internet through so I am on a local machine in the network. Im using PHP to try and send email. I tried configuring my php.ini file but i get an error:=

```
Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 587, verify your
"SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() 
in C:\wamp\www\buyme\views\forms\register_form.php on line 226
```

line 226 is where i send an email the default mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
Do I need to download and install something else for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have sendmail functionality so its only option is to use SMTP to send mail via another mail server.

Assuming you have the mail settings configured correctly for the mail server you are trying to use. You may depending on your network, be restricted from sending traffic out on the smtp port in use. To verify this, use command prompt and try to open a telnet connection to the mail server on the specified port. You should see some sort of hello message if this works. If not, you may have a firewall somewhere blocking you.

Some SMTP servers require TLS/SSL when sending mail. I'm not sure if PHP supports this with the base mail command, but other mail libraries can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosting's registration email which includes ftp settings, login settings etc. whether there's any information about a SMTP server which you can use in your application. If not, ask your hosting provider if any SMTP service runs on your hosting. If any, ask for it's settings. Maybe there's a different port/security configuration that you don't know.